# verify this proof to be valid or not?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Question- Suppose ABC is a triangle such that the lengths of AB, BC, CA are all rational numbers. Prove that, for all positive integer n, cos(nA) is a rational number.

My Reasoning: since cos(A) is rational because sides are rational so cos(nA) being a polynomial of cosine on expansion, it is too rational.

Is this a good proof, i would like you all to give some alternate better proofs for this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your reasoning is good, only you should say something about why the sides being rational implies the cosine is rational.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Can i use consine law to prove that?

Comment: @Shaun I seldom use it because jax is too complicated

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) and of the multiplication formula. In fact $$\cos \gamma = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab},$$
and this proves the claim for $n=1$. The general statement is obtained by expanding $\cos (n \gamma)$ as a polynomial in $\cos \gamma$.